# How to change setState in (then) so as not to get an error?

Tags: reactjs, setstate, gmail.js

```js
const submitEmail = () => {
    emailjs
      .sendForm(
        ".....",
        ".....",
        data.current,
        "...."
      )
      .then(
        (res) => {
          props.setReady(true);
          setStatusMailJS("Письмо отправлено"); //i get error
        },
        (error) => {
          props.setReady(true);
        }
      );
  };
```

how to change State so as not to get an error?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhRJs.png)

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap your set state code inside if condition, with useRef react hook

```
let isRendered = useRef(false);
useEffect(() => {
    isRendered = true;
    emailjs
      .sendForm()
        .then(res => {
            if (isRendered) {
               props.setReady(true);
               setStatusMailJS("Письмо отправлено");
            }
            return null;
        })
        .catch(err => props.setReady(true););
    return () => {
        isRendered = false;
    };
}, []);
```

Comment: but submitEmail function work on click Button